# Is it common that SEO companies do not work without a CMS? Some won't touch our static website

Tags: seo, wordpress, cms, static

I have recently developed a website for a client. but there is an issue that has popped up.

In the beginning, there was always the talk about after development of the website, we would add a web application. Their previous website was build static and hosted on firebase and it seemed that the client was very happy with the way it was working so we decided to just stick to that way, since it would be easy for us to implement a react application into the website with it built static and from scratch.

Now the website is live and they have paid a SEO company to do some work on the website, but they do not work on websites that do not have a CMS.

I do not work with SEO, so my questions are these:

Is it common that SEO companies do not work without a CMS?

If I were to implement a CMS only for SEO sakes, would WordPress be the ideal way?

Comment: There is a divide in the SEO world. SEO on a CMS is easy and quite frankly lazy and limited. Any quality SEO will work with what you have. I would not advise changing from static to anything else. SEOs that only work with a CMS are out for the fast and easy buck and likely not terribly knowledgeable about SEO but rather CMS plugins and settings. Go for the SEO with a deep understanding of how search works.

Comment: 100% agree with @closetnoc. I've worked on sites ranging from WordPress and Drupal, to static, to the kind of CMS that enervates all involved. The principles of SEO are the same. But with static, you get no shortcuts. You have to know how to code, know the meta tags and understand JSON files. Any SEO that won't is like a developer who says he only works with frameworks and won't work with vanilla JavaScript. Get your money back from those people and hire a real SEO.

Comment: Thanks abuch for these answers, its very insightful. We have come to the conclusion of i will recive the changes to be changed in the meta tags and titles.